# Is there any way we can call the next variable are call before?

Tags: javascript, function

**If there was a way, we would assign the value of the next variable to a variable and use it for some other purpose.**

```js
if(h){
  console.log('welcome to your ' +h);
}
const h='home';
```

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want?

Comment: If you mean redefine a variable: `yes`, constant: `no`. If you mean use an variable before it was defined: `no`;

Comment: like h are called befor pass the values

Comment: It's not possible the read the value of a variable before it's assigned to the variable.

Comment: @vanowm Variable declarations with `var` are hoisted. You can use a variable before it is defined in the code because it's actually defined at the top of the scope. It doesn't work with `let` or `const`

Comment: @jabaa, Are you sure you are mistaken with functions? If that was true OP example would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @vanowm The assignment isn't hoisted but the variable already exists and is undefined until you assign a value (only with `var`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#only_declarations_are_hoisted I also used the term "definition" synonymous to "declaration". There is no variable definition in JavaScript.

Comment: To me this seems like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Perhaps you could provide the context that explains _why_ it is you are trying to accomplish it, and the community might be able to provide you with better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use function for your case! this is the example

```
function image(x){
    console.log("welcome to your " + x)
}

const h = "home"
image(h)
```

Comment: without use function but any ways?

Comment: You don't need `x` argument, since function can access variables in the same scope it's in.

Comment: Not sure, i think function is the best and easier way @vishalJenny